# How to write a path of folder from network

Tags: php, file, networking, path, scandir

I am writing a script using PHP to copy all the files from network. But how can I write the path of this folder?

```
$origin = "Network\\Project\\Images";
```

The result is as following:

```
Warning: scandir(Network\Project\Images,Network\Project\Images): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in C:\wamp\www\test\copyFile8.php on line 44
```

If the path is local, like: `C:\\...`, that can work. But I don't know how to write a remote path.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `\\\\Network[...]` ?

Comment: Is it a linux or windows server that's holding the files? How are you connecting to the network? (i.e. samba, etc)

Comment: Do you mean writing like: $origin = "\\\\Network\\Project\\Images"? I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: It a windows server, I'm not sure how it connecting to network. How can I figure out that?